# How do I take a reference to `sin`?

Tags: perl, reference, subroutine

I can define a subroutine and take a reference to it like this

```
sub F { q(F here) }
$f = \&F;
print &$f           # prints “F here”
```

But how can I do the same with, e.g., `sin`?

```
$f = \&sin;
print &$f           # error: Undefined subroutine &main::sin called
```

That sounds as though I should be able to use `\&MODULE::sin`;
 evidently `cos` is not in `main`, but which module is it in?  I do not see that documented anywhere.

Comment: You should avoid the use of the ampersand `&` whenever possible. You need to use it when taking a reference to a subroutine, like `my $f = \&F`, but you should call that reference with `$f->()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`sin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sin.html) is not in your current package. You need to call it from [the `CORE::` namespace](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html). `CORE::` is where all the built-in functions reside. It is imported automatically.

```
my $f= \&CORE::sin;
print $f->(1);
```

Output:

```
0.841470984807897
```

---

Knowing about `CORE::foo` is mostly usefull if you want to call the original built-in after a function was overwritten.

```
use Time::HiRes 'time';

say time;
say CORE::time;
```

This outputs:

```
1442913293.20158
1442913293
```

Comment: You know, I tried `core` and `Core`, but not `CORE`.  I guess I knew this at some point :-).

Comment: @xebtl me too. But then I remembered. Note that there is also `CORE::global::` to overwrite stuff.